# Get information like pitch or amplitude from audio byte in an array

Tags: c#, audio, fft

I want to get the pitch in Hz of an audio byte in an byte array.
This is my code now:

```
        byte[] wav = File.ReadAllBytes("test.wav");
        for (int i = 44; i<wav.Length; i++)
        {
            // wav[i] is an audio byte, channel shifts every 2 bytes (I think)
        }
```

At first I thought that the wav file is built with hundreds or thousands of chunks, that every chunk contains a sample rate, so I tried to scan the whole array for another byte sequence that represents the word "WAVE" which is a part of a chunk, but the sample rate is only at the beginning of the array, and after place 44, all of the array is just the audio data itself.
The audio byte is just a hexadecimal value, I cant understand how can I get any information from that value.

UPDATE: I have downloaded Math.NET library which has FFT algorithm.
this is the documentation for the FFT: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms/Fourier.htm
I have read all of the methods there but I don't know what method will do what I want (give it a few bytes of the wav file and get their frequency).

UPDATE 2:
Now I am using Accord library for the FFT, I found a tutorial for that in youtube.
This is my code for convert the audio bytes to double array:

```
            for (int i = 44; i<wav.Length; i+=BufferSize)
        {
            float currentSec = (float) audioLength / wav.Length * i;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

            for (int j = 0; j < buffer.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((i + j + 1) < wav.Length)
                    buffer[j] = wav[i + j];
            }

            int SAMPLE_RESOLUTION = 16;
            int BYTES_PER_POINT = SAMPLE_RESOLUTION / 8;

            Int32[] vals = new Int32[buffer.Length / BYTES_PER_POINT];
            double[] Ys = new double[buffer.Length / BYTES_PER_POINT];
            double[] Ys2 = new double[buffer.Length / BYTES_PER_POINT];

            for (int k = 0; k < Ys.Length; k++)
            {
                byte hByte = buffer[k * 2 + 1];
                byte lByte = buffer[k * 2 + 0];

                vals[k] = (int)(short)((hByte << 8) | lByte);
                Ys[k] = vals[k];
            }
            Ys2 = FFT(Ys);

            double avgFrq = AverageFromArray(Ys2);

            if(lastSecond < (int) currentSec)
                lastSecond = (int) currentSec;

        }
```

FFT Function:

```
       private double[] FFT(double[] data)
   {
        double[] fft = new double[data.Length];
        System.Numerics.Complex[] fftComplex = new System.Numerics.Complex[data.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            fftComplex[i] = new System.Numerics.Complex(data[i], 0);
        }

        Accord.Math.FourierTransform.FFT(fftComplex, Accord.Math.FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            fft[i] = fftComplex[i].Magnitude;
        }

        return fft;
    }
```

So to check if it works I made a wav file that is just a white noise at the frequency of 5000Hz, but These are the results I get from FFT (values of a 2048 bytes array):
https://pastebin.com/PUq5bQTn
The whole audio file has the same frequency of 5000Hz but my code gives me values like 605.80502914453746 and 4401.1090268930584

Comment: What do you mean "pitch of an audio byte"? The array is a digital capture of an audio stream at a particular sampling rate - each byte represents the amplitude at the moment in time it was sampled - as such the byte does not have a pitch. You need to perform some sort of audio analysis of the entire array (or a portion of it) to get the pitch of that period of time.

Comment: You will need to read and analyze the header.

Comment: @PaulF what is the minimal time period I can analyze and get its pitch? how can I do that?

Comment: @TaW I analyzed the header but it just contains the general sample rate, I want to capture every change in pitch in that file and use it later.

Comment: @Eldar: to do that you need to do a series of FFT-transforms for different time intervals of the audiostream. For each interval you can determine the pitch from the frequency spectrum and process them further. Of course the assumption here is that your audiostream contains only a small frequencyband at a time, which is not the case with e.g.music, speech...

Comment: @EldarAzulay: You need to research audio analysis - the more samples you use the better the frequency resolution.

Comment: Before you can find changes you would need to find pitch. Simple for a sine wave, really really hard for music, impossible for sound.

Comment: @JohanDonne It could be helpful if you send me an example of FFT-transform, I am new to this stuff.

Comment: You will need to find a suitable library - implementing FFT is quite complex. You will probably find the library will have example code. You may find several C# implementations if you try google - these will probably do the job but may not be particularly efficient. The Intel IPP libraries which are available for free are very efficient but may not be the easiest of a beginner to use. Try googling for an FFT tutorial - translating from the time domain (WAV array) to frequency domain needs some understanding before you can progress.

Comment: @PaulF sorry for the trouble, but I've gooled FFT tutorial, but I don't understand how can I use FFT for audio, it could be helpful if you send me a good tutorial that talks about the basics of FFT and how I use audio with it. I am a really dummy on that subject..

Comment: It is very complex but to find the pitch you need to find the dominant frequency of a waveform. A waveform can be represented as the sum of multiple sine waves at a particular frequency and amplitude - the FFT converts the waveform into those individual frequency components. The top part of this tutorial explains it without any real maths : http://dmorris.net/projects/tutorials/fourier_tutorial.pdf. In the example the pitch is likely to be taken as the third peak as it has the highest amplitude.

Comment: Understanding what pitch really is is quite complex there are some explanations here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847633/net-library-to-identify-pitches with a possible library/project that may be useful in the very last answer.

Comment: @PaulF chekc out my updated question about Math.NET. They have FFT algorithm but I just need some explanations about how to use it with my code. currently I just have a byte array of all of the audio data from that file. I want to get changes in frequency from the audio data using that FFT.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not used that library & the documentation appears very limited, so I cannot really be of help. What you are doing is quite complex - you really do need to do some studying on how the FFT works & what the data returned really means. Without a fuller understanding of the FFT you could be getting spurious results - simply taking a chunk of data & applying the FFT can give unexpected frequencies due to the sharp cutoff at each end of the sample unless you apply some form of windowing.

Comment: As you appear to have very limited understanding of digital signal processing - then I do recommend you try to find a complete solution, as doing it yourself requires understanding of some complex things. FFT is not the only solution - auto correlation is another technique - [this library](https://pitchtracker.codeplex.com/) claims to be a completed solution based on that technique. Again I haven't used the library, so cannot really be of any help. To download the library use the Source Code tab on the link.

Comment: Here is a good introduction to the basics of FFT without going into the maths if you are interested : http://download.ni.com/evaluation/pxi/Understanding%20FFTs%20and%20Windowing.pdf

Comment: @PaulF I've made some progress, I found a library for FFT and read a tutorial. The problem is that I get wrong frequency values. I will edit the question with my current code and example for the values.

Comment: A fundamental undestanding of the maths involved is essential for any kind of audio analysis - library documentation is not likely to fill this gap.

Comment: @EldarAzulay - sorry I cannot be of further help - as I said earlier you have a very limited understanding of what you are trying to do & the extra information you have added just goes on to show that. "White noise" is defined as _"noise containing many frequencies with equal intensities"_ - so to speak of _"white noise at the frequency of 5000Hz"_ does not make too much sense. You have not yet grasped the basics of FFT if you do not understand the values being returned & try to average them - that makes no sense at all. I repeat my suggestion you find a ready made solution.

Comment: @PaulF I am really new to this audio programming. I would love to learn it from the basics and if you have a good tutorial you can suggest me to start learning it would be great.

Comment: You may want to try the [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) to ask for resources - but as marko said _"A fundamental understanding of the maths involved is essential for any kind of audio analysis"_ - any decent book is going to have some very complex maths involved. I learnt the fundamentals 35+ years ago, so I doubt any books I used are still available - so all I can suggest is google. A quick search brought this page up - https://dspguru.com/dsp/books/favorites/ - I can't vouch for any of the books mentioned though.

Comment: @PaulF thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid your code (and question) is overly naive.

1. A Wav file is not just a collection of audio samples. Have a look at (e.g.) http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/ for a description of the file format and its stucture.
2. If you want to read, process, write audio files, there are different libraries out there (e.g. NAudio) that will help a lot.
3. From 1 sample in the audiostream you can never calculate the pitch. To do that you need a (relatively large) number of samples and calculate the frequency spectrum using an FFT transform.

Comment: Nice link, I was searching for such a header description. :-)

Comment: I was just reading that before I posted that question, this figure is so good it helped me a lot to understand the structure of a WAV file.

Answer (score 4):

`WAV` is data is just pulse code modulated ([PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation)). This means that every value represents an actual point of the audio signal.

Wav files have a header, you can find some info about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757712(v=vs.85).aspx). It describes how the file is structured.

If you meant by "pitch" the fundamental frequency of the sample, try an  [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)

Amplitude is the value at a certain point, but beware, you need to take these variables into account:

- bits ber sample
- byte order
- block align
- channel count

Comment: See @JohanDonne's answer for a better link to the header structure: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: When analysing digital audio - the pitch is normally defined as the fundamental frequency of the sample (ie highest amplitutude frequency)  - _"Pitch is the difference in playback and original sample rate "_ sounds more like a pitch shift.

Comment: I meant frequency analysis, I just dont know how to implement the FFT

Comment: @PaulF: Yes, I indeed misunderstood that part of the question, I'll update it.

Answer (score 2):

1. A single FFT magnitude peak is a poor and often inaccurate way to measure musical pitch, as pitch is a more complicated psychoacoustic phenomena.
2. There is a time-frequency trade off in estimating frequency, usually proportional to sampleRate/blockLength.  So using 44 sample blocks at a sample rate of 44100, the frequency estimation error will be on the order of 44100/44 or around +-1000 Hz (perhaps depending on stationarity and the signal-to-noise ratio).

Comment: can you define `blockLength`?

Comment: The length of the DFT.